# Matching Credit Card regexs in groups of 5

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble with a regex for Credit Cards. I have a document which contains several card numbers. I would like to match these card numbers in groups of 5 (i.e. 8 card numbers in a document gets matched in groups of 5,3 respectively). What I have so far is:

```
(((((\b4|\b5)([0-9]{3}[\W]?)([0-9]{4}[\W]?){3})))(\D+|\b)){1,5}
```

Card regex work fine, but I'm having problems in matching them in groups of 5.

Example **1** matches correctly. But in example **2**, every match is an individual card number.

1. https://regex101.com/r/57KqZe/7
2. https://regex101.com/r/57KqZe/8

What am i doing wrong here? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you please give a link to regex101 rather than screenshot?

Comment: Plus, we don't necessary know how is formatted card numbers. Would you please add examples with expected results?

Comment: If I remember well, there's an algorithm that checks if a card number is valid or not. This can't be achieved by regex. Regex will only check the format, not the validity

Comment: Screenshot_2: https://regex101.com/r/UfGaAn/1

Comment: Screenshot_1: https://regex101.com/r/55DHBE/1
I just want to match them not check for valid or not.

Comment: Try it like that: [`((\b5[1-5][ -]*[0-9]{2}[ -]*[0-9]{4}[ -]*[0-9]{4}[ -]*[0-9]{4}\b|$)|(\b4[0-9]{3}[ -]*[0-9]{4}[ -]*[0-9]{4}[ -]*[0-9][0-9]{3}\b|$)){1,5}`](https://regex101.com/r/55DHBE/2)

Comment: Hi, in your example, there are 7 matches. What i want to do is, if there is 6 cards in a text for example, the match whould be 2.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] and is not yet compleye enough to receive answers.